# Why does my SQL Server CURSOR loop exit early based on the calling client?

Tags: sql-server, vba, ms-access, odbc, cursor

I'm using SQL Server 2019 to parse a CSV file. The stored procedure has a single integer parameter that identifies which CSV file to process. I put the CSV file into its own table to ensure there wasn't a linefeed-related problem between the caller and the server OS. By passing in an id, I guarantee they are all using identical data.

When I execute the procedure interactively in SSMS or Azure Data Studio, it works great. When I call it from Python (pyodbc) or VBA (ADODB), it process 50-60 rows (it varies) of the 77 rows; it doesn't raise an exception, and the rows it *does* process are correct.

I've trimmed the code down as far as I can, trying to eliminate causes. I've tried using variations of "LOCAL STATIC READ_ONLY FORWARD_ONLY TYPE_WARNING" as part of the cursor declaration, but that has no effect. Not surprising, since the table being looped isn't changed inside the loop.

The code below *fails*, i.e. doesn't complete, as it's written. If I comment out the INSERT inside the loop, it runs to the end, saying it processed 77 rows. I thought the problem was in the `usp_parse_row`, but it fails with that commented out. Clearly, it's not "processing" anything with this loop. There's nothing strange about the CSV file, and as I mentioned, the code runs perfectly when I run it from within SSMS/Azure Data Studio.

Thank you for any suggestions.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[xyzzy_import_file]
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE
     @msg varchar(2048)
    ,@row VARCHAR(500)
    ,@content VARCHAR(500)
    ,@row_num INT
    ,@counter INT
    ,@this_proc_name sysname = CONCAT(QUOTENAME(OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(@@PROCID)), '.', QUOTENAME(OBJECT_NAME(@@PROCID)))
    ;

    SELECT @msg = CONCAT('Hi, ', 'Mom!');
    INSERT INTO debug_log (log_tx, procedure_nm) VALUES (@msg, @this_proc_name);

    DECLARE rows CURSOR FOR 
        SELECT row_id, content 
        FROM rows_to_import
        ORDER BY row_id;
    OPEN rows;

    SELECT @counter = 0;
    FETCH NEXT FROM rows INTO @row_num, @row;

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 BEGIN
        SELECT @counter = @counter + 1;

        SELECT @content = @row;  -- Copy cursor value to separate variable (superfluous?)
        SELECT @msg = CONCAT(@counter, ': ', @content);  -- Create a message for debugging.
        INSERT INTO debug_log (log_tx, procedure_nm) VALUES (@msg, @this_proc_name);  -- Save the debug message.
        --EXEC usp_parse_row @content  -- Process the row.

        -- Finished processing row.
        FETCH NEXT FROM rows INTO @row_num, @row;
    END

    CLOSE rows;
    DEALLOCATE rows;

    SELECT @msg = CONCAT('Processed ', @counter, ' rows.');
    INSERT INTO debug_log (log_tx, procedure_nm) VALUES (@msg, @this_proc_name);  -- Save the debug message.

    RETURN @counter
END
```

Comment: Where is the CSV file coming from? I would also ask why you are using a cursor for this? SQL Server 2019 has inbuilt tools for handling CSV files.

Comment: The CSV is coming from a third party report. I'm using a cursor to iterate over each row in the CSV file, parsing the data and performing business logic with them. What "inbuilt tools" do you mean? I'm not importing the file manually. I'm writing an application in which the end user submits the CSV file.

Comment: Generally speaking, the first executed statement in a procedure should be "set nocount on;" to avoid sending messages that application often do not expect and / or cannot handle correctly. Give that a try.

Comment: *"What "inbuilt tools" do you mean?"* `BULK INSERT` and the `FORMAT = 'CSV'` parameter.

Comment: And the reference to "csv file" is very misleading. Doesn't matter where those rows come from - your cursor is using a table. Is anything else updating the table at the same time? Perhaps adding another logging message that includes the number of rows (in the table) at the start of the loop and the number of rows at the end of the loop.

Comment: @Smor yes; in the simplified version, I also put the data into a table. But you're right--the CSV isn't the source of the problem.
Larnu I've overlooked BULK INSERT several times, and I don't know why. Ironically, the CSV file might end up being a problem, because the numeric fields include '$' and thousands-separator commas.  I'll look into BULK INSERT now.

Comment: Perhaps before the cursor, test the count of records and log the count?  Maybe add the schema just in case you are not using the correct table?  SELECT @count = COUNT(*) FROM dbo.rows_to_import

Comment: What's the etiquette to mark this question closed? Although my direct question wasn't answered (everyone's suggestions were things I had already tried in coming up to the simplified code I posted), Larnu's suggestion of the `BULK INSERT` statement has taught me to fish, rather than feeding me for a day. Thank you, all, and especially @Larnu.

Comment: Questions that are off-topic are closed, @Daniel'Dang'Griffith . If you've answered the question yourself then you can always post your own answer.